# Parsing Meta Tag using xPath

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, web-scraping

How can I parse a Meta Tag such as

```
<meta itemprop="email" content="email@example.com" class="">
```

..and extract the email out of it.

When I copy the xPath of this tag, I get the following, which doesn't work

```
//*[@id="businessDetailsPrimary"]/div[2]/div/meta
```

Please advise.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The likelihood is that the `itemprop="email"` attribute will be unique across the webpage. In this case, you can select the email by accessing the `content` attribute via its `XPath` as follows:

```
//meta[@itemprop="email"]/@content
```

**[Demo](http://xpathfiddle.net/Z8VBSY)**

In case `itemprop="email"` is not unique, you can make your `XPath` more specific by selecting the element with `id` equal to `businessDetailsPrimary` first:

```
//*[@id="businessDetailsPrimary"]//meta[@itemprop="email"]/@content
```

**[Demo](http://xpathfiddle.net/NCEBG8)**

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your prompt response. It works perfectly. One more thing, I am also trying to extract the addresses using xPath but the location of the address isn't always the same through the pages, example the following:

http://yellow.co.nz/y/wally-sutherland-tauranga
http://yellow.co.nz/y/first-commercials-waipukurau

..any way to handle such situations?